# Does the order of references to jQuery matter?

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jQuery. I encountered a problem when referencing to jQuery in masterpage of my project (you can find part of my masterpage below). I wanted to use datepicker in a page, so I added a set of references (jQuery ui and css) in head above another set of references (for any other jquery throughout my project), but when I ran it, it kept giving me "jQuery undefined" alert.

The interesting thing was if I move the set of refs for datepicker down after the other set (just like the order  shown below), it worked properly. I don't know if its about the order when rendering the page. Any info would be appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--date picker-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--date picker-->
</head>
```

Comment: jquery-ui is built extending the functionality jQuery. So if you do not reference it before that obviously it won't understand a thing right.. So jQuery library comes first , then the plugins should come after that.. The browser parses the code top-down.

Comment: Thanks for the help, to Xander , sushanth and Sean.your answers help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is executed (by default) in the order the `script` tags are encountered in the DOM - if you load some library which has a dependency before you load its dependency you will get errors (as you discovered)

See: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async

> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these attributes. If the async attribute is present, then the script will be executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. If the async attribute is not present but the defer attribute is present, then the script is executed when the page has finished parsing. **If neither attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.**

*Emphasis mine*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JavaScript is parsed "top-down".

All dependencies need to be referenced before the dependant reference.